# Android slow soft keyboard opening

Tags: android, android-fragments, keyboard, android-softkeyboard, soft-keyboard

I have a really annoying problem. A made registration form in android and when an EditText get focus the keyboard comes up. But its really slow. It takes 5 sec or more even on high-end devices.

Our application is using fragments in several layers. So i thought maybe calculating all these layers to slide up(when the keyboard comes up) takes this long. When i set "adjustNothing" in the manifest file keyboard shows quickly, and in another activity where we have only one layer of fragments(this layer is the registration form) it also comes up quickly.

Anyone have a similar problem or suggestion? (hiding or removing fragments below the registration is not an option )

Comment: Are you having the issue on hardware or emulators?

Comment: I'm also having a problem with the keyboard coming up very slow and it is in just a regular activity that I made into a form.  It is a older phone but I don't remember having this problem a few years ago on the same device.  Hopefully its not something that changed in one on the SDK updates and you can find an answer.

Comment: This is an issue on emulator and hardware too. For e.g. on the new Nexus 7 shows the keyboard slowly too.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem twice. There aren't many topic around about this :(

I solved the first one by setting `android:isScrollContainer="false"` in the ListView
and `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` in the main Layout of the Fragment in which the EditTexts are located.

The second one is just a Fragment that contains a ListView, and it's still a problem :'(